# Trying to make a Google sheets formula to change the value of a cell based on the range of a value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I’m trying to change the value of column D starting with row 12 and ending at row 103 based on the corresponding C value next to it. I want the column D cell to say “Wine”  if the column C cell has a value of 89 or higher. If it’s between 78 and 88 to say “Cinnamon”. If. It’s between 67 and 77 to say “Mustard”. If it’s between 66 and 76 to say “olive drab. And if its 65 or less to say chocolate brown.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKgY0.png)

I tried using an array formula but I don't really understand functions so it didn’t work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, including the spreadsheet settings, like the locale, as it affects the formula syntax. Besides adding an image, add sample data for input and the corresponding expected result as text. Also, considering that there are thousands of questions about [tag:google-sheets] add the most relevant related questions and why they don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this within `Cell_D12` of your test sheet*

```js
=let(Σ,{0  ,"brown";
        56 ,"olive";
        67 ,"mustard";
        78 ,"cinnamon";
        89 ,"wine"},
     index(if(len(C12:C103),ifna(vlookup(C12:C103,Σ,2,1)),)))
```